# objectタグで外部サイトを埋め込んだとき、iOSではスクロールができない

Tags: onsen-ui, iphone, html5

現在、Monacaを利用したスマホアプリ開発行っており、ページのいくつかは
アプリ内で外部サイトを閲覧できる必要があります。（外部ブラウザはNG）

その際、objectタグを利用して表示しておりますが
Androidだと正常に（スクロールしてページの一番最後まで）表示できるのですが
iPhoneだと最初に表示された以上の領域が表示できません。
途中で切れているので下へスクロールもできません。

Android、iPhone共に同じソースを使用し、以下のような書き方をしています。

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left"><a href="home.html">HOME</a></div>
    <div class="center">サイト表示</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<object id="○○" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" data="http://www.△△△/□□□.html">
```

どうすればiPhoneでも正常な表示ができるでしょうか？
何故、同じソースでデバイスが変わるとこのようなことが起こるのでしょうか？

Comment: スタイルでサイズの指定は行ったのでしょうか？、、でも、正直な話、表示するサイトの内容や、OSの仕様に縛られるのでいたちごっこですし、InAppBrowser（ https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser ）を使うのは駄目でしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
InAppBrowserは一度検討したのですがどうやっても「アプリ内の指定した領域に埋め込んで表示」ができなかったので使うのをやめました。
InAppBrowserは使ってみた感じだと基本的に新しいページを開くために使うものと思いますがアプリ内の特定の領域に「埋め込み」はできるものでしょうか？
「埋め込み」にこだわる理由は、デザインの都合と<ons-toolbar>にもありますがこのページのタイトルと「HOME」ボタンを必ずこの位置に表示する必要があるからです。